# Where can I find a list of cities within each county?

Tags: usa, data.gov, us-census, census

I found some lists for some states, e.g. https://georgia.gov/municipality-list, but not for all counties in the US...

Comment: One way to find open data [is to search this site](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+cities+county) !

Comment: geonames.org should have this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [U.S. City and County Web Data (API)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7/u-s-city-and-county-web-data-api)